# Caching third party data - Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am new to ASP.net caching, I have a scenario where I am getting data from third party web service.

We are trying to cache data received from webservice! So next time user makes the request we fetch data from cache. Below are the two types of data.

- Static Data - Never changing data
- Dynamic Data - Data which may or may not change.

Static data will be always remain static for a user, Dynamic data changes from time to time based on user actions!

We have decided to cache static data into database so all next subsequent request will serve data from Database.. We are planning to get dynamic data from web service as soon as users logins and clear the data once users logs out and refresh the data once users perform certain action.

We are confused with storing Dynamic data at our end, intially we thought of storing it into session but problem we are predicting is if this data grows that might make session heavy! At present we are getting 30-40 object as a part of dynamic data! This may increase in future! Should we store Dynamic data in database or Cache? Or should we continue using session for storing Dynamic data?

Comment: Is there data common across all users (i.e. application level data) or every user has different data from one another ?

Comment: Different for each user that's the reason we are not going with application state

Comment: You can use **ASP.NET State Server** to keep session data or save (and then remove) on SQL server. Try what better works for you.